# Set a delay between two instructions in R

Tags: r

How to Set a delay time between two instructions in R ,

```
For (i in 1:N){
instruction 1
- delay time -
instruction 2
}
```

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like you are looking for [`Sys.sleep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.sleep.html).

You would do:

```
for (i in 1:N){
  instruction 1
  Sys.sleep(time_in_seconds)
  instruction 2
}
```